# Mounting NFS Folder on to a Remote Machine (Both machines are on Red Hat Linux)

Tags: linux, redhat, mount, nfs

I'm a newbie to Linux and would need some advice on the thing I'm trying to achieve with regards to mounting a NFS Folder

I have a NFS Server: usanfsd01 And a remote machine: usafssd01

I've a software installed on my remote machine "usafssdo1" and it takes the files that come into the NFS Server "usanfsd01" as input for execution so I'm thinking I should mount the NFS Server onto the remote machine. Please validate if my thinking is correct.

Also, if I mount the NFS Server on to remote machine using the following command, will it be a permanent mount

```
mount usanfsdo1:/home/files /home/mount/files
```

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong

Answer (score 1):

The first part is correct.

The second part  is not, at least not entirely. The mount will not be permanent but lost after the next reboot.

Add the following line to `/etc/fstab` instead:

```
usanfsdo1:/home/files /home/mount/files  nfs    rw  0  0
```

This mount will be restablished after a reboot. After you first added the line, you can do the initial mount with

```
mount /home/mount/files
```

Comment: I added that line and tried to mount but then I receive the following error message, can you please advise

[mntent]: line 17 in /etc/fstab is bad
mount: can't find /home/mount/files in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. There was a typo and also it looks like I've an access issue. I will figure it out with IT.Thanks for your help. I highly appreciate it

Comment: OK, but I missed to mention that the directory `/home/mount/files` has to exist for this to work.

Comment: Yes, the folder exists. Right now the error is,

mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting usanfsd01:/home/files

Comment: check that the host is indeed exporting that "share" with showmount -e usanfsdo1   You should see /home/files listed if it is.